# Java formatted converting double to String

Tags: java, string, formatting, double

I have this:

```
double indPay;
double indPayment[];
DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
```

But when I do this:

```
indPay = myFormat.format(indPayment[q]);
```

I get:  `Type mismatch.  Cannot convert from String to double.`

Why is this?

EDIT:  Is there any way of formatting a double without going thru this string process?

Comment: As an aside, you should probably use an integer type to do payment/currency manipulations.

Comment: @Jems Why would I use integer if there will be decimals?

Comment: A formatter will format, i.e. convert to string. To convert a String to something else you need a parser. Here you are assigning the result of formatting (a String) to a double reference variable

Comment: @KickingLettuce for accuracy. Floating point types can accrue inaccuracies, and results of expressions like 0.5 + 0.5 == 1.0 can be false.

Comment: Keep your doubles as doubles. Only format when you need to display the result as a String.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  That is exactly why I needed to format.

Comment: Keep your doubles as doubles, unless they'd be better off as `BigDecimal` - for example, if you're using them for money.  Never store money as `double`.  As Jems pointed out, `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` returns false, which tends to annoy the accountants.

Comment: @DavidWallace: true, true!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indPay is a double and you are trying to store a string in it;
try `String str = myFormat.format(indPayment[q]);`